# Interlocking shapes with clipping mask and stroke

Tags: adobe-illustrator, clipping-mask

I'm trying to create something like this:

[image]

(Ignore the gray diagonal line)

I have the female symbol and the rainbow flag. I know how to add stroke, create clipping masks, and create interlocking solid-color shapes with the live paint bucket, but I can't put everything together to make this design. The logical way, I think, would be to "bring forward" or "send backward" a part of a shape by selecting nodes, but I don't think that's possible. How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, create a **Gradient**:

[image]

You can get hard edges in a gradient by placing color stops at the *same* location. For example, above there is a red **and** an orange color stop both at 15%, then an orange **and** a yellow color stop both at 30%, then repeated for yellow/green, green/blue, blue/purple.

Then, draw one shape. Duplicate and move it. Use the **Shape Builder Tool** to drag across areas that need to appear on top... and lastly apply the gradient you just made.

[image]

<sub>(Final colors here are a bit muddy due to gif dithering.)</sub>

---

If you *must* use a **Clipping Mask**, the overall construction is the same.. duplicate shape and use the **Shape Builder Tool**.

Then..

- **Copy** both shapes.
- Move your image to be clipped into place and behind the shapes
- Select the image and first shape and choose `Object > Clipping Mask > Make`
- Repeat for the second shape

Now if you **want a stroke** on all of it, adding strokes to clipping masks can be problematic. it is often best to replicate the mask path to add the stroke. To do this.... since I *copied* the shapes already and they are on the clipboard.

- Choose `Edit > Paste in Front`. This will paste the shapes I copied *exactly* in the same position where they were copied, but on the top of the object stack.

From here, it's just a matter of removing the fill and adjusting the stroke.

[image]

So this builds 2 clipping mask shapes, then 2 additional shapes on top for the strokes.

[image]

When it's all aligned things look as they should...

[image]

Just select all and `Object > Group` to keep it all together.

Comment: really nice tutorial!

Comment: Yes really nice. I was a couple of minutes from posting my solution using clipping mask on a duplicate of one of the symbols to create the overlap, but this is better ...

Comment: My gradient is a bit sloppy though. It could be better defined :)

Comment: @Scott I didn't think of using a gradient instead of a clipping mask. Nice!

Comment: @Wolff If you feel like posting it, I'm interested in learning how to do this with a clipping mask, in case I need to do it with a photograph or something like that.

Comment: @ironcito OK, maybe I'll do it later, but even for photos I think this method would work fine.

Comment: Answer updated with a clipping mask @ironcito

Comment: Actually I meant using a clipping mask to create the interlocking effect, but with this method it's not necessary.

Comment: Ahh.. old school @Wolff  More work since the intro of Shape Builder.